# I want only the section name in my header, not the section number

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

I have a problem regading fancy headers. I want to have the section name only in my header, but when I am using the following code I get the section number as well:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\arabic{section}.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
```

Anyone knows a way to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! The number is printed by `\arabic{section}` on the third line, so just remove that, and the following dot and space `.\ `.

Answer (score 7):

The line

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\arabic{section}.\ #1}}
```

sets the section mark to consist of
  - the section number as a Arabic numeral
  - followed by a fullstop and space
  - followed by the section name

Just us

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
```

instead to remove the number and accompanying punctuation.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

You will probably want to make similar changes to `\subsectionmark` too, i.e.

```
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
```

Comment: @Elin: Instead of saying `thank you` only, please consider to accept the answer!